# Huge CPU usage difference for the same .NET 4 program on different machines

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

I have two servers, one running core i7 920 (8 logic CPUs at 2.8Ghz), the other running Xeon X3430 (4 logic CPUs at 2.4Ghz). For the same .NET 4 application, CPU usage on the first machine is 6%; on the second machine it is 50%! I wonder what makes this huge difference. And how can I diagnose the cause of the issue?

Comment: Are you referring to a single CPU's usage at 50%, or all of the CPU's usages?

Comment: Are you expecting 2 different CPUs to give the same performance ?

Comment: No, the CPU usage is the overall value. I was expecting the usage on the slower machine to be at most twice, or 12%, not 50% (8 times difference).

Comment: The two cpus have different architectures and different number of cores.  You cannot compare them like this.

Answer (score 2):

Its not just CPU that matters, are you saturating IO? Is the faster machine so much faster that it is writing much more data that the CPU cannot keep up, whereas the slower machine is rattling along and so the CPU fully utilised.

Locking might also have a part to play, I know a simple test app I wrote a long time ago showed large performance differences between a single core and quad core systems. (the single core was a lot faster, I think .NET optimised away locks for it whereas the quad core suffered).

In short, unless there's a fair bit more information on the problem, no-one can give you anything other than guesses as to the cause.